# Combining tabs and drawer in react native expo app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native expo app that makes use of react navigation 6. I can display the tabs and the drawer however i get this console warning

```
Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check

Home, Home > Home

Profile, Profile > Profile
```

and this is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AnimatedSplash from "react-native-animated-splash-screen";

import Home from './screens/Home';
import Profile from './screens/Profile';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function TabsNavigator() {
  return (
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen 
      name="Home" 
      component={Home} 
      options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen 
      name="Profile" 
      component={Profile} 
           options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="user" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

 function App() {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(true);
  }, 3000);
  
  return (
  <AnimatedSplash
      translucent={true}
      isLoaded={loading}
      logoImage={require("./assets/splash.png")}
      backgroundColor={"#FFFFFF"}
      logoHeight={650}
      logoWidth={550}
    >
  <NavigationContainer>
  
   <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabsNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={TabsNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  
  </NavigationContainer>
    </AnimatedSplash>
    
    

  );
}

export default App
```

As a result of the warning when i tap on the home link on the drawer, i cannot visit the home component. How can i correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

change the name for one of these routes, every screen must have a unique name.

Here,

*In Tab Screens the names (name="Home") and ("name=profile")

And In Drawer Screens the names (**name="Home"**) and (**"name=profile"**).

Can't be similar if the code is nested as in your case.
Simply change the names of Drawer Screen slightly as  (**name="HomeDrawer"**) and (**"name=profileDrawer"**) and the issue will be resolved.*

***And update your modules to version 6.x.***